# React and Use State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

Just practicing with intro React Use State and can't figure out what is wrong here when attempting to add a counter and a random user number generator button

Here is the code

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Projects from './components/Projects';
import List from './components/List';
import Resume from './components/Resume';
import Bio from './components/Bio';


const App = () => {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  let [userNames, setUserNames] = useState(['shannonYoung', 'zoraJackson', 'giavannaClark'])
  let [userNameIndex, setUserNameIndex] = useState(0)

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1)
  }

  const decrement = () => {
    setCount(count - 1)

    let [userNameIndex, setUserNameIndex] = useState(0)

    const randomUserNameIndex = () => {
      let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * userNames.length)
      setUserNameIndex(randomNum)
    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <h1>My Portfolio</h1>
      <p> test count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
      <button onClick={decrement}>-</button>

      <h2>Hello {userNames[userNameIndex]}</h2>
      <button onClick={randomUserNameIndex}> Change User </button>
      <Projects />
      <List />
      <Resume />
      <Bio />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

Compiled with problems:X

```
ERROR

[eslint] 
src/App.js
  Line 22:45:  React Hook "useState" is called in function "decrement" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 37:24:  'randomUserNameIndex' is not defined                                                                                                                                                                                                             no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: I would say this error is pretty self-explanatory. You can't call useState inside function decrement, you can only call it at the root of your react component (like you did for count for example). Plus you're re-declaring userNameIndex which you already declared at the start of your component. How about you just remove that useState line from your decrement function ?

Comment: and also you've defined a randomUserNameIndex function inside decrement that you've never called.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
    let [userNameIndex, setUserNameIndex] = useState(0)
```

from `decrement` function. As the error message says, hooks are supposed to be defined either at the component level, or in another hook. You need the former.

Comment: I was able to fix it using this solution, thank you!